# mCrypt not present after Ubuntu upgrade to 13.10

Tags: apache, ubuntu

After I have upgraded my system from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 several problems have occurred with apache, mysql and php configurations.

I solved most of them but I can't seem to get mCrypt library working.
Package is installed so i don't need to apt-get it. Server works and everything seems fine, but when I try to run `php artisan serve` with Laravel 4, I get a message that mCrypt is required.

I did `php --ri mcrypt` and the output was `Extension 'mcrypt' not present.`
I have tried putting `extension=mcrypt.so` to `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep php5`

```
libapache2-mod-php5         install
php5                        install
php5-cli                    install
php5-common                 install
php5-gd                     install
php5-json                   install
php5-mcrypt                 install
php5-mysql                  install
php5-readline               install
```

Comment: Are you sure it's installed `dpkg --get-selections | grep php5`

Comment: apt-get install php5-mcrypt ?

Comment: I have updated question with output of @tlenss command. `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` outputs that it is installed and newest version

Comment: Maybe the answer here will help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/360646/cant-use-php-extension-mcrypt-in-ubuntu-13-10-nginx-php-fpm

Comment: Found launchpad bug on that page that gave me solution. Thanks

Answer (score 273, accepted):

I think I found the solution at [launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mcrypt/+bug/1241286).

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, in OpenCart 1.5.6 this issue was causing the error...

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv() in /<path here>/system/library/encryption.php on line 8

Comment: Of note, this solution did not work for me with Laravel/Artisan until I **also** sym-linked in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d

Comment: I am getting this error.Which code i have to update?In which file i need to update?Kindly suggest..

Comment: This was causing Webgility not to sync. Installing it fixed it up right nice. Thanks!

Comment: in the case of Ubuntu 14.04/PHP5.5 this will need to be `sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/a
pache2/mods-available` just a heads up.

Comment: With Ubuntu 14.04/PHP5.5 the first line is not needed. php5enmod makes the link.

Answer (score 27):

I had this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and I did the following to resolve it:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This is what worked for me, I have PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4, and I didn't have a /etc/php5/conf.d directory.

Answer (score 14):

I also have this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 after install.

First enable the mcrypt

```
sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Add this command in any line

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Create conf.d folder in /etc/php5

```
sudo mkdir conf.d
```

And inside that folder create mcrypt.ini file

```
sudo gedit mcrypt.ini
```

Then add this command to that file

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Then create a link to file

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
```

Enable mcrypt module

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: You don't need `extension=mcrypt.so` in `php.ini`. It's working also without it, as php extensions (like mcrypt) are in separate `.ini` files.

Comment: @machineaddict For me adding the 'extension=mcrypt.so' worked after installing the mcrypt.  Lubuntu 14.04 Trusty Thar. I was not automatically loaded

Answer (score 11):

From Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Works for me.

Comment: For me: `WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php5/mods-available`. However, the file was located somewhere else. `sudo cp /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/` and ran the commands above. Taken from [www.devraju.com](http://www.devraju.com/about-me/ubuntu-13-1014-04-mcrypt-missing-fatal-error-undefined-function-mcrypt_encrypt/)

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and Nginx,but the tip for me was restart the FPM service, so I did:

Install the library

> apt-get install php5-mcrypt

Find the path

> updatedb && locate mcrypt.so

Set the path of mcrypt.so inside the mcrypt.ini file located in /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini

> extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so

And then restart the FPM service

> service php5-fpm restart

Comment: I just needed to apt-get install php5-mcrypt and than service php5-fpm restart on my ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Nice..In my case in needed to find the mcrypt lib manually because the extension was empty in the mcrypt.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if the package is already installed:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall php5-mycript
```

This worked for me after doing upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with PHP 5.5.14 running on Mac OS X Yosemite. I was trying to install Laravel 5.0. And when I tried to create a new project I got an error like below (even when I tried to start the laravel server with *php artisan serve*

```
Alejandros-MacBook-Pro:Documents Lexynux$ laravel new blog
Crafting application...
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/blog/config/app.php on line 83
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/blog/config/app.php on line 83
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
Compiling views
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/blog/config/app.php on line 83
Application key [CCOPocoMjnJTx4AFXk64wqyTKyo3BlHq] set successfully.
Application ready! Build something amazing.
Alejandros-MacBook-Pro:Documents Lexynux$
```

So I just added the line below at the end of my php.ini file with the nano editor:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
sudo nano /etc/php.ini
```

Finally just restart the Terminal and restart the laravel app server with

```
php artisan serve
```

And it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

just found on php.net

> Note, for Ubuntu, simply installing php5-mcrypt did not get mcrypt to work. You need to execute the following commands as root to enable it:

```
apt-get install php5-mcrypt
mv -i /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/
php5enmod mcrypt
service apache2 restart
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php#114609

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this "problem" occurs because you entered an artisan command on your local machine instead of on your virtual machine. If you are using Homestead, mcrypt is already installed. Consider it a reminder to `homestead ssh`