# My composer won't update completely with Laravel 4 it gets stuck with artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]  
Error Output:

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

This shows after:

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

I tried to delete all my folders in my vendor folder. But that did not change anything.

I am using MAMP server on my Mac OS X.

PHP Version 5.4.10

mcrypt 2.5.8

I just tried "sudo composer update --verbose" and I got this error:

```
sudo composer update --verbose
Password:
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:
    Exception trace:
     () at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:148
     Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:107
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchCommandEvent() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:289
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:118
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:897
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/bin/composer/bin/composer:43
 require() at /usr/bin/composer:15
```

Here is the error I found in my PHP error logs:

```
[04-Nov-2013 20:45:44 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/-----/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46
```

I just tried to test my composer:

```
sudo composer diagnose
Password:
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking composer.json: FAIL
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
Name "andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site" does not match the best practice (e.g. lower-cased/with-dashes). We suggest using "andrew13/laravel-4-bootstrap-starter-site" instead. As such you will not be able to submit it to Packagist.
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

Just applied the recommendation in the error message from the last command. Now everything is showing as OK.

I just tried this:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
```

I am now getting new errors in my PHP Error logs:

```
[05-Nov-2013 05:45:45 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class config does not exist' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php:165
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php(165): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php(142): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config', Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php(444): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php(233): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config')
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php(3151): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('config')
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php(103): Illuminate\Exception\ExceptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Exception\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php(163): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illum in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 165
```

Comment: The exception message is missing from the verbose output, pretty hard to say anything without it.

Comment: I just added more information. Is there something else missing? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Okay, the runtime exception has no message as it seems but the log entry is clear. Composer is unable to autoload the `Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup` file. This can have various reasons. My guess, the vendor's composer file has incorrect autoload settings.

Comment: I never touch these settings. I just tried to update my Lavarel 4 setup.

Comment: Sure, but it seems that a composer configuration from one of the projects is wrong. Or a file is missing from the file system.

Comment: I just did composer diagnose and I saw they were two errors in composer.json. The strange thing is that I never encountered any problems in the past. I will try to debug it and re-test.

Comment: I just updated my question. I did some tests and it shows that my settings for composer are OK.

Comment: I added `chmod +w path/to/vendor` and it worked like a charm

Comment: seems like this is just a bad error message and can show up due to any number of reasons. the `composer dump-autoload` advice below seems most likely to solve things. i'm having this problem too though, about to try that out myself.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe this error results from not being able to find `mcrypt`.

> Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

Apparently it is not quite that easy to install `mcrypt`.

1. Install the `php5-mcrypt` package, or verify that it has been installed correctly.

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
   ```
2. Check whether `mcrypt` has been installed and enabled for PHP:

   ```sh
   php --ri mcrypt
   ```
3. You're done if it says:

   ```
   mcrypt support => enabled
   ```

   Otherwise, continue if it says:

   ```
   Extension 'mcrypt' not present.
   ```
4. Verify that `mcrypt.ini` is present in PHP's `mods-available` directory.

   ```sh
   ls /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
   ```
5. If it says `No such file or directory`, create a symbolic link from `mcrypt.ini` to PHP's `mods-available` directory.

   ```sh
   sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
   ```
6. Enable the mod.

   ```sh
   sudo php5enmod mcrypt
   ```
7. Restart apache.

   ```sh
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
8. Check again whether `mcrypt` is enabled.

   ```sh
   php --ri mcrypt
   ```

The final steps were inspired by [Vuk Stanković](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19447669/146622).

Comment: I was having a similar problem and this helped me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mcrypt is already on my system and composer has been working fine for awhile until I got this error

Comment: `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Okay, did some further research with Google and it seems that this has to do with the autoload caching from Composer. There are various ways on how you can solve this.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

This would re-create the autoload stuff for you and it *should* solve your problem for now.

If this doesn't help, try deleting *everything* and re-install fresh: <sup>[[ref]](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1572)</sup>

```
rm -rf /path/to/composer.lock /path/to/vendor/
composer install
```

This would re-create just about everything.

Comment: Nop, not working. I get: Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

Comment: I deleted the composer.lock found at the root of my web app but I did not remove the composer.lock inside some of the vendors.

Comment: Seems like a very common problem (e.g. stackoverflow.com/questions/18127347/). But it also seems like there's no real solution that works for everyone. You should post your question in the artisan support forum (GitHub or wherever that is).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your laravel install did not run correctly and since part of the `composer.json` runs the `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize` if your laravel application is not working then composer will fail.

Try running your composer update without invoking the Laravel scripts.

```
php composer update --no-scripts
```

After that you can either run the commands from the scripts block in your composer.json manually. Else you can just run a standard

```
php composer update
```

again which will run the scripts for you.

Comment: I tried the first command but I got this error: "touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied". I have no idea what this is.

Comment: I deleted composer.lock and the folder vendor. And I tried the first command and it worked. But the second command gives me: "Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error"

Comment: Here is a new error I am getting: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class config does not exist' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/---/bootstrap/compiled.php:165
Stack trace:

Comment: To see more just look at the end of my question.

Comment: do you have write permissions on that directory?

Comment: The directory that your composer.json file is in, also the vendor directory (and children).

Comment: I solved the "touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied" by executing
sudo rm -rf ~/.composer/
This seems to be composer's cache directory.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to install `mcrypt`.
In ubuntu execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Then update composer:

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for me, setting `xdebug.scream = 1` gives problem:

1) Find xdebug configuration file.

```
$ sudo find / -name xdebug.ini
```

2) Edit file using any text editor.

```
$ sudo vi /your_path/xdebug.ini
```

3) Set `xdebug.scream = 0`

4) Reload server

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to run composer update and none of the solutions above had worked. It turns out I had 2 require sections in my composer.json which is actually wrong.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.*",
    "zizaco/confide": "3.2.x",
    "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "2.*",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev"
}
```

Combining the two as below solved my issue.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.*",
    "zizaco/confide": "3.2.x",
    "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master"
},
```

If you still have a problem, try deleting the composer.lock and the vendor directory and run

```
mv ~/.composer/cache ~/.composer/cache.bak
```

To clear the composer cache and finally run

```
sudo composer install
```

This should solve the issue.