# mcrypt on Cloud 9

Tags: mcrypt, cloud9-ide, php-5.5

I have a php workspace with a fresh copy of laravel. The problem i'm having is that mcrypt is missing so laravel doesn't want to work. How can I install mcrypt onto my workspace so that laravel will work?

I've tried the c9pm but it doesn't seem to be a command anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new cloud9 workspaces give you sudo rights. You can use sudo apt-get install to install the plugin you want.

Comment: It was actually already installed I just had to enable it. I just followed these steps to enable it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21769562/1318205