# Run time composer error in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I get the following error when i update composer in laravel 4

```
Nothing to install or update
Reading ./composer.lock
Generating autoload files
Executing command (CWD): php artisan clear-compiled

Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cfm_mgt_sys\bootstrap\start.php on line 14
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:



Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:177
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:91
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:342
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:140
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:146
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:25


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|v
vv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Please can someone help as to how to go about solving this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not a composer problem, composer just run post-update command from laravel framework.

Try "php artisan clear-compiled" and you'll get the same error.

Check your laravel installation (this question should help: 
[My composer won't update completely with Laravel 4 it gets stuck with artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775012/my-composer-wont-update-completely-with-laravel-4-it-gets-stuck-with-artisan) )

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I followed the link and have gone through that question but I don't seem to know how to move forward with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    delete the composer.lock file

run
    composer dump-autoload

    php artisan dump-autoload

then 

composer update
```

Comment: When I run php artisan dump-autoload i get the error Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cfm_mgt_sys\bootstrap\start.php on line 14

Comment: paste me what you have on this line C:\xampp\htdocs\cfm_mgt_sys\bootstrap\start.php on line 14

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\cfm_mgt_sys>php artisan dump-autoload

Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cfm_mgt_sys\bootstrap\start.php on line 14

Comment: I mean open the file start.php with your editor and paste what is on line 14

Comment: line 14  $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;