# mcrypt.ini doesn't exist in my directory

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lamp, mcrypt

I'm using ubuntu 13.10. I  need mcrypt extention on my terminal. My server already have installed it. I follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446679/mcrypt-not-present-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-13-10) and [lunchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mcrypt/+bug/1241286).
So I execute this commant:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But when I try to above second line  `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` command, Then I see a warning:

> WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under
>   /etc/php5/mods-available.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you checked whether the first line created a soft link at _/etc/php5/mods-available_ ?

Comment: yea. I was check. and this link was available.

Comment: So try create a [hard](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-hard-links-with-ln-command/) link instead. This must be _sudo ln /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini_ before that make sure to remove the early added soft link from _/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini_

Comment: @LeoPrince I did this but again an error `ln: accessing ‘/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini’: No such file or directory`

Comment: _accessing ‘/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini’: No such file or directory_ This seems like you are trying to access a non existing file. Try _php --ini_ command to see the existing .ini files for php.

Comment: "Try php --ini command to see the existing .ini files for php. –  Leo Prince Jan" I did this but this mcrypt.ini file is not available.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Install mcrypt for php5,

Command:

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php5-mcrypt
```