# Laravel 4 - problems with composer

Tags: php, macos, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to execute this command(below)

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel TestApp --prefer-dist
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



[RuntimeException]  
Error Output:       



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-     url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [package] [directory] [version]
```

I've cheked:

> php -v

PHP 5.4.24

> sudo composer diagnose

Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK

any idea??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the mcrypt extension for PHP, which is a requirement for Laravel. Depending on what system you are, or just search for **mcrypt extension**.

- [OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595841/installing-mcrypt-extension-for-php-on-osx-mountain-lion)
- [Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446679/mcrypt-not-present-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-13-10)

edit: just saw your osx tag, then the first link should cover it.

Comment: you are right. The problem is it's using a wrong php version. I have followed the steps the guy says in the post but it´s not working. I set ".bash_profile" and I have added export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH but when I type which PHP doesn't print the path I've added and also I still getting the same problem. any idea??

Comment: didn't you say, your `php -v` outputs 5.4.24 instead of 5.5.10?

Comment: I installed 5.5.10. I followed the steps of the post you sent me and it's working ok.. so thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

On linux you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

if you are on a mac could try:

http://topicdesk.com/downloads/mcrypt/mcrypt-download

Comment: I'm using mac :-s. I've tried the link you sent me and nothing.