# Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH

Tags: php, apache, mcrypt

After reinstalling our server, `MCRYPT` is no longer working and PHP gives the notice

> Use of undefined constant `MCRYPT_BLOWFISH` (`Apache 2.4`, `PHP 5.5`).

php -m returns mcrypt.

> ```
> ls -al /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/
> 20-mcrypt.ini -> ../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini
>
> cat /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
> ; configuration for php MCrypt module
> extension=mcrypt.so
> ```

Why is `mcrypt` not recognized? How can I make this work?

Comment: See: http://www.madcapsule.com/blog/php-mcrypt-magento-error

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I had already tried that. I have libmcrypt4 installed.

Comment: I've come across the exact error.  And that site doesn't work.  From what I can tell, the MCRYPT constants don't exist :/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No sooner do I speak do I find a solution, heh.

This worked for me:
[mCrypt not present after Ubuntu upgrade to 13.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446679/mcrypt-not-present-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-13-10)

needed to go:
sudo php5enmod mcrypt

even though it appeared to already be enabled, that fixed it.

Comment: "sudo php5enmod mcrypt" did the trick! For other readers: restart apache after this with the command "sudo service apache2 restart"

Comment: this worked for my laravel/homestead vagrant box https://gist.github.com/Artistan/ee25f22f5e931b7ee46f3d6167d87e5f

Answer (score 4):

When I try to enable the Express Paypal method, I came across this error.

> Error: Use of undefined constant `MCRYPT_BLOWFISH` - assumed `MCRYPT_BLOWFISH` in `/var/www/.../lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php` on line 56

Firstly, we can run this cmd to check the `mcrypt` is running or not:

```
php --ri mcrypt
```

If `mcrypt` is not enabled, we can use the following to enable it as others mentioned

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

As well, we had better check `php5-mcrypt` package is installed or not

```
dpkg -l | grep php5-mcrypt
```

While if you install `fastcgi` and `php-fpm` like us, we have to restart the `php-fpm` service, and `apache2` service as well.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service php-fpm restart
```