# Error when serving Laravel app for the first time

Tags: php, laravel

I just installed Laravel 5 through composer and it was installed globally on my mac. Now when I try `laravel new blog` and try to serve it on apache by `php artisan serve` i get the following error

```
ErrorException in compiled.php line 6635:
Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'
```

I get this everytime i deploy a new app. How to i solve the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of undefined constant MCRYPT\_BLOWFISH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608625/use-of-undefined-constant-mcrypt-blowfish)

Comment: mcrypt extension installed or enabled?

Comment: bro, do you even google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Laravel 5 Installation page](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements) you can see the requiments section, which states that in order to use the framework, you need Mcrypt extension installed and enabled.

The Laravel framework has the following system requirements:

> PHP >= 5.4
>
> Mcrypt PHP Extension
>
> OpenSSL PHP Extension
>
> Mbstring PHP Extension
>
> Tokenizer PHP Extension

You need to install and enable these extensions in order to use the framework.

Comment: Mcrypt was not installed. Got that. Thanks :D